# What are the pros/cons of using a web-framework vs pure HTML/JS in a mobile web application?

Tags: mobile, client-side, server-side, web-frameworks

Very keen on seeing this debate unfold.

We are in a debate over developing a enterprise mobile-web application for an existing SOA.

One side is of the opinion that the entire application could be built using HTML and a JS library all client-side, the other side is of the opinion that the application should use a server-side mobile web framework such as Rails or similar.

This isn't a debate over JS libraries or Server-Side frameworks, just a conversation about the best practice for a project like this.

Go!

Comment: If you want this question to stay open, I'd mark it as Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a best practice here - it all depends...  Suitability of existing codebase, skills, timescales, costs, etc.

If your services are well suited for reuse in a web application, it seems wasteful to rewrite them. This doesn't preclude SOAP, though it would be a bit more work. If you have a RESTful interface already, bingo.

If your services aren't already web services, it may still be easier to write a REST or WS  layer on top of your existing APIs and expose existing functionality.

As a last resort, rewrite from scratch. It's more expensive, and has a much lower success rate than you may think. However, if your existing code isn't really finished, and the tech stack isn't well suited to your (assumedly) final goal of a web app, now might be a good time to make a big change.

Are all of the service calls you will need for the web app extant?  Remember stuff like analytics, logging, and authentication.  If you need to write them, how will they need to interact with your existing data and code?

If you are building anything more than the most dinky toy app, you should have reliability, scalability and performance concerns. These all have varying degrees of difficulty depending on your implementation decisions. What's most important to you? It can be hard to write these into existing codebases.

Personally I like writing the client side code. I would rather expose open, reusable RESTful services and construct a web app to consume them. I would also prefer refactoring and reuse over rewriting whenever feasible.